# I want to create a new variable in css by adding the class

Tags: css

```
.theme-light{
--primary-color:white; 
}
```

It is `--plimary-color` in `root`.
But when this class added I want it as `--primary-color_theme-light` How to make it

Comment: The idea with css variables is to make them dynamic (output by PHP for example). So, dynamically change `:root { --primary-color: white;}` and do not add theme classes at all - just use `color: var(--primary-color);`. You can [read more about css vars](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties).

Comment: Why did you try to format the text with `<blink>`? Even if it would work that would be really annoying and something you should not do. Formattings are there to structure your question.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you want to use the value stored in `--primary-color_theme-light` instead of writing `white`?

Comment: What you are describing already works, a CSS variable cascades in the same way as an inherited style. [Example snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/ds3uafrm/)

Comment: Yes in rootit is - - primary-color but when that light theme is applied is there any way that i can change it to --primary-color_theme-light buy dynamically there are large number of variables like that it is an angular project.